# Query returning different number of rows, results in crosstab error

Tags: postgresql, crosstab, pgadmin

I get this error with my query, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it:

> Query-specified return tuple has 135 columns but crosstab returns 295.

And here's my query: (The part highlighted in bold returns same number of rows when run separately in pgAdmin.)

```
SELECT X.*, pi.productcode, pi.productitemdesc, pi.retailsalesprice, cat.productcategorydesc FROM ( 
SELECT * FROM crosstab ( 
'SELECT a.productitem AS productitemid, l.locationcode, (CASE WHEN SUM(a.netamount) IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(a.netamount) ELSE 0 END) || ''#'' || (CASE WHEN SUM(a.quantity) IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(a.quantity) ELSE 0 END) AS sales_qty FROM invoiceitem a INNER JOIN invoiceinfo b ON a.invoice = b.invoiceid INNER JOIN locationinfo l ON b.location = l.locationid WHERE b.status !=2 AND l.locationtype = 1 AND l.status = 1 AND TO_CHAR (b.invoicedate, ''YYYY-MM-DD'')>=''2018-03-01'' AND TO_CHAR (b.invoicedate, ''YYYY-MM-DD'')<=''2018-03-03'' GROUP BY a.productitem, l.locationcode ORDER BY a.productitem', 
'SELECT l.locationcode FROM locationinfo l INNER JOIN invoiceinfo b ON b.location = l.locationid
 WHERE b.status !=2 AND l.locationtype = 1 AND l.status = 1 AND TO_CHAR (b.invoicedate, ''YYYY-MM-DD'')>=''2018-03-01'' AND TO_CHAR (b.invoicedate, ''YYYY-MM-DD'')<=''2018-03-03'' GROUP BY l.locationcode order by l.locationcode') 
 AS (productitemid int, "0007" text,"BE101" text,"BE1013" text,"BE1014" text,"BE102" text,"BE103" text,"BE1034" text,"BE104" text,"BE1040" text,"BE1043" text,"BE1044" text,"BE1045" text,"BE1046" text,"BE105" text,"BE106" text,"BE107" text,"BE108" text,"BE109" text,"BE110" text,"BE111" text,"BE112" text,"BE123" text,"BE1265" text,"BE1266" text,"BE1271" text,"BE1272" text,"BE1273" text,"BE1274" text,"BE1279" text,"BE1280" text,"BE1281" text,"BE1282" text,"BE1351" text,"BE1400" text,"BE1401" text,"BE1404" text,"BE141" text,"BE142" text,"BE193" text,"BE194" text,"BE2125" text,"BE2126" text,"BE2127" text,"BE2128" text,"BE3001" text,"BE3002" text,"BE3005" text,"BE3006" text,"BE3009" text,"BE3010" text,"BE3031" text,"BE3032" text,"BE3121" text,"BE3122" text,"BE3123" text,"BE3124" text,"BE3127" text,"BE3128" text,"BE3131" text,"BE3132" text,"BE3203" text,"BE3204" text,"BE325" text,"BE3253" text,"BE3254" text,"BE326" text,"BE332" text,"BE3503" text,"BE3504" text,"BE355" text,"BE356" text,"BE365" text,"BE366" text,"BE381" text,"BE382" text,"BE383" text,"BE384" text,"BE400" text,"BE401" text,"BE402" text,"BE403" text,"BE405" text,"BE406" text,"BE408" text,"BE409" text,"BE411" text,"BE412" text,"BE4311" text,"BE4316" text,"BE4401" text,"BE4402" text,"BE4521" text,"BE4522" text,"BE4551" text,"BE4552" text,"BE470" text,"BE473" text,"BE475" text,"BE481" text,"BE482" text,"BE601" text,"BE604" text,"BE609" text,"BE610" text,"BE7040" text,"BE7043" text,"BE7045" text,"BE7046" text,"BE7048" text,"BE7049" text,"BE708" text,"BE7111" text,"BE7112" text,"BE7127" text,"BE7128" text,"BE7217" text,"BE7218" text,"BE7307" text,"BE7308" text,"BE7351" text,"BE7352" text,"BE801" text,"BE802" text,"BE803" text,"BE804" text,"BE831" text,"BE832" text,"BE860" text,"BE861" text,"BE862" text,"BE863" text,"BE865" text,"BE981" text,"BE982" text 
 )) X
 LEFT JOIN productitem pi ON X.productitemid = pi.productitemid
 LEFT JOIN productcategory cat ON pi.productcategory = cat.productcategoryid
```

The bold part of

```
productitemid int, "0007" text,"BE101" text,"BE1013" text,"BE1014" text,"BE102" text,"BE103" text,"BE1034" text,"BE104" text,"BE1040" text,"BE1043" text,"BE1044" text,"BE1045" text,"BE1046" text,"BE105" text,"BE106" text,"BE107" text,"BE108" text,"BE109" text,"BE110" text,"BE111" text,"BE112" text,"BE123" text,"BE1265" text,"BE1266" text,"BE1271" text,"BE1272" text,"BE1273" text,"BE1274" text,"BE1279" text,"BE1280" text,"BE1281" text,"BE1282" text,"BE1351" text,"BE1400" text,"BE1401" text,"BE1404" text,"BE141" text,"BE142" text,"BE193" text,"BE194" text,"BE2125" text,"BE2126" text,"BE2127" text,"BE2128" text,"BE3001" text,"BE3002" text,"BE3005" text,"BE3006" text,"BE3009" text,"BE3010" text,"BE3031" text,"BE3032" text,"BE3121" text,"BE3122" text,"BE3123" text,"BE3124" text,"BE3127" text,"BE3128" text,"BE3131" text,"BE3132" text,"BE3203" text,"BE3204" text,"BE325" text,"BE3253" text,"BE3254" text,"BE326" text,"BE332" text,"BE3503" text,"BE3504" text,"BE355" text,"BE356" text,"BE365" text,"BE366" text,"BE381" text,"BE382" text,"BE383" text,"BE384" text,"BE400" text,"BE401" text,"BE402" text,"BE403" text,"BE405" text,"BE406" text,"BE408" text,"BE409" text,"BE411" text,"BE412" text,"BE4311" text,"BE4316" text,"BE4401" text,"BE4402" text,"BE4521" text,"BE4522" text,"BE4551" text,"BE4552" text,"BE470" text,"BE473" text,"BE475" text,"BE481" text,"BE482" text,"BE601" text,"BE604" text,"BE609" text,"BE610" text,"BE7040" text,"BE7043" text,"BE7045" text,"BE7046" text,"BE7048" text,"BE7049" text,"BE708" text,"BE7111" text,"BE7112" text,"BE7127" text,"BE7128" text,"BE7217" text,"BE7218" text,"BE7307" text,"BE7308" text,"BE7351" text,"BE7352" text,"BE801" text,"BE802" text,"BE803" text,"BE804" text,"BE831" text,"BE832" text,"BE860" text,"BE861" text,"BE862" text,"BE863" text,"BE865" text,"BE981" text,"BE982" text
```

AND

```
SELECT l.locationcode FROM locationinfo l INNER JOIN invoiceinfo b ON b.location = l.locationid
 WHERE b.status !=2 AND l.locationtype = 1 AND l.status = 1 AND TO_CHAR (b.invoicedate, ''YYYY-MM-DD'')>=''2018-03-01'' AND TO_CHAR (b.invoicedate, ''YYYY-MM-DD'')&lt;=''2018-03-03'' GROUP BY l.locationcode order by l.locationcode
```

When run seperately, I get 295 results which is correct. However putting it together in the whole query gets the error.

Comment: if crosstab returns 295 columns and if you return it all , then number of column should be 295 in return. If you just need 135 columns crosstab should only retunr 135

Comment: "same number of rows" ... same as which number? Am I right in assuming your column `invoiceinfo.invoicedate` is type `timestamptz`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for comment, I have put in the details in my updated question. TQ !

Comment: @parladneupane thanks for comment. If i separate out the two queries, I get same number which is 295, however when I put into the whole query I get the error. 
I have updated my question. Hope that explains more. 
Thank you very much

Comment: @Sylph: What about the data type?

Answer (score 2):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.48.4.7)

> The remaining output columns must have the type of the last column of the *`source_sql`* query's result, and there must be exactly as many of them as there are rows in the *`category_sql`* query's result.

`crosstab(text, text)` with a dynamic (!) `SELECT` query as 2nd parameter is very error prone, since the output column list is static. You should also generate the output column list dynamically. Example:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

That aside, the different number of rows returned from the same query, may very well be due to a different `timezone` setting in the two different sessions.

You have the expression `TO_CHAR(b.invoicedate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` in your predicates. If `b.invoicedate` is **type `timestamptz`** the result depends on the `timezone` setting. Consider:

```
SET timezone = '+10';
SELECT TO_CHAR(timestamptz '2018-04-07 23:30+0', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

to_char
----------
2018-04-08

SET timezone = '-10';
SELECT TO_CHAR(timestamptz '2018-04-07 23:30+0', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

to_char
----------
2018-04-07
```

#### Solution

To remove the dependency on the `timezone` setting, use absolute values.

- `to_char()` is expensive complication in this place to begin with. Drop that and adjust the predicate.
- Provide `timestamptz` values to match your column. This also allows indexes to be used (if applicable).

  - [Return Table Type from A function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502767/return-table-type-from-a-function-in-postgresql/24512834#24512834)
- Use time zone names (not offsets or abbreviations) to avoid more misunderstandings.

  - [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- Use dollar-quoting to clean up the quote mess.

  - [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

I suggest this as 2nd parameter:

```
$$
SELECT l.locationcode
FROM   locationinfo l
JOIN   invoiceinfo  b ON b.location = l.locationid
WHERE  b.status <> 2 AND l.locationtype = 1 AND l.status = 1
AND    b.invoicedate >=  timestamptz '2018-03-01 Europe/Vienna'
AND    b.invoicedate <   timestamptz '2018-03-04 Europe/Vienna'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1
$$
```

Replace `Europe/Vienna` in my example with the time zone name defining your dates.
Note `2018-03-04` to include all of 2018-03-03 like you intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just checked and the invoice data type is : timestamp without timezone. 
If that is the case, do you have any idea what could be wrong? I tried to use your method too , but still have the same error.
Btw, thanks a lot for your help above, learning something new everyday.