# Error to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Pls Help!

```
count_rate := 
(
SELECT COUNT(trate.rid) AS count_rate 
FROM tlot LEFT JOIN trate ON trate.ridlot = tlot.lid 
GROUP BY tlot.lid
);
```

FULL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION editstatuswait()
  RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE count_rate INTEGER;
BEGIN
  count_rate := (SELECT COUNT(trate.rid) AS count_rate FROM tlot LEFT JOIN trate ON trate.ridlot = tlot.lid GROUP BY tlot.lid);

  IF (count_rate != 0) THEN
    UPDATE tlot SET lstatus = 3
    WHERE tlot.lexpirationdate < NOW()
    AND tlot.lexpirationdate > NOW()-INTERVAL '24 hours' AND tlot.lstatus = 2;
  ELSE
    UPDATE tlot SET lstatus = 0
    WHERE tlot.lexpirationdate < NOW()
    AND tlot.lexpirationdate > NOW()-INTERVAL '24 hours' AND tlot.lstatus = 2;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

> ERROR: [21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression Где: SQL statement 
>   `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(trate.rid) AS count_rate FROM tlot LEFT JOIN trate ON trate.ridlot = tlot.lid GROUP BY tlot.lid`

I can not understand how to get rid of this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will depend on what you are trying to achieve.

A variable can only contain a single value, so your attempt to store the result of a subselect that returns more than one row in `count_rate` is bound to fail.

You will have to come up with a subselect that returns at most one row (if it returns no row, NULL will be assigned to the variable).

- If you are only interested in the first row (unlikely, since there is no `ORDER BY`), you could append `LIMIT 1` to the query.
- If you want only the count for a certain `tlot.lid`, you should use `WHERE tlot.lid = ...` instead of a `GROUP BY`.
- If you want to process multiple results, you would use a construction like:

  ```
  FOR count_rate IN SELECT ... LOOP
     ...
  END LOOP;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
count_rate := (SELECT COUNT(trate.rid) AS count_rate FROM tlot LEFT JOIN trate ON trate.ridlot = tlot.lid);
```

Of course, this may not do what you intend.  It will at least fix the error.

Comment: The error corrected, but yes, it does not do what it takes :(

Comment: @MaksimParkhomenko, check this url to learn [how to loop one data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339628/cursor-based-records-in-postgresql)